# cmake library compilation mingw issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, mingw

Apologies in advance I am beginner in cmake, the answer may be obvious but I didn't find it yet. 
I am using cmake 3.0.2 and I am trying to build a library and then use that library in a executable (and later more executable). It is currently working (configure, generate, compile, execute) with MSVC (version 2013), however it doesn't work with mingw 4.8.1 nor g++ 4.8 on linux. 
I only have two directories, the library (with the include) and the executable source. 
the root CMakeLists.txt is:

```
IF(NOT MSVC) 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-std=c++11") 
ENDIF() 

include_directories ( 
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libr-source 
${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libr-source 
) 

add_subdirectory(libr-source) 
add_subdirectory(libr-executable)
```

the one in the libr-source is:

```
project(libr) 
include (GenerateExportHeader) 

set ( CXX_SRCS 
    codeMessage.cpp 
    codeMessage.hpp 
        libr_export.h 
) 

add_library(libr SHARED ${CXX_SRCS}) 
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER (libr)
```

and in the executable:

```
set(PROJECT_NAME "librExecutable" ) 

project(${PROJECT_NAME}) 

set (SRCS 
    main.cpp 
) 

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRCS}) 
target_link_libraries (${PROJECT_NAME} libr)
```

Thank you for your help!

below the results of compilation:

```
C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming>C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\mingw32-make.exe VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -HC:\Users\user\dev\librTest -BC:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\CMakeFiles C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/Users/user/dev/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
C:/Users/user/dev/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/mingw32-make -f libr-source\CMakeFiles\libr.dir\build.make libr-source/CMakeFiles/libr.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\user\dev\librTest C:\Users\user\dev\librTest\libr-source C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-source C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-source\CMakeFiles\libr.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-source\CMakeFiles\libr.dir\DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-source/CMakeFiles/libr.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-source/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-source/CMakeFiles/libr.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target libr
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
C:/Users/user/dev/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/mingw32-make -f libr-source\CMakeFiles\libr.dir\build.make libr-source/CMakeFiles/libr.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\CMakeFiles 1
[ 50%] Building CXX object libr-source/CMakeFiles/libr.dir/codeMessage.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-source && C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\g++.exe   -Dlibr_EXPORTS -std=c++11 @CMakeFiles/libr.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\libr.dir\codeMessage.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\user\dev\librTest\libr-source\codeMessage.cpp
Linking CXX shared library liblibr.dll
cd /d C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-source && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\libr.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\libr.dir/objects.a
C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\libr.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\libr.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\g++.exe     -shared -o liblibr.dll -Wl,--out-implib,liblibr.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\libr.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi3
2
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\CMakeFiles  1
[ 50%] Built target libr
C:/Users/user/dev/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/mingw32-make -f libr-executable\CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\build.make libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" C:\Users\user\dev\librTest C:\Users\user\dev\librTest\libr-executable C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-executable C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-executable\CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\DependInf
o.cmake --color=
Dependee "C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-executable\CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-executable/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming/libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target librExecutable
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
C:/Users/user/dev/MinGW-4.8.1/bin/mingw32-make -f libr-executable\CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\build.make libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/buildmingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming' 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\CMakeFiles 2
[100%] Building CXX object libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/main.cpp.obj
cd /d C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-executable && C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\g++.exe    -std=c++11 @CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/includes_CXX.rsp   -o CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\main.cpp.obj -c C:\Users\user\dev\librTest\libr-executable\main.cpp
Linking CXX executable librExecutable.exe
cd /d C:\Users\user\dev\libr-buildming\libr-executable && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a
C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\objects1.rsp
C:\Users\user\dev\MinGW-4.8.1\bin\g++.exe  -std=c++11    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o librExecutable.e xe -Wl,--out-implib,liblibrExecutable.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ..\libr-source\liblibr.dll.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x70): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11codeMessageC1Ev'
CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN11codeMessage10getMessageEm'
C:/Users/user/dev/mingw-4.8.1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): bad reloc address 0x0 in section `.ctors'
C:/Users/user/dev/mingw-4.8.1/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
libr-executable\CMakeFiles\librExecutable.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'libr-executable/librExecutable.exe' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [libr-executable/librExecutable.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:124: recipe for target 'libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libr-executable/CMakeFiles/librExecutable.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/user/dev/libr-buildming'
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: what does `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1` show?

Comment: I just added the result of this compilation, I am going to work I will have a closer look at it later today.